# How to use merges folder in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have worked on the ionic framework and I really liked it.I have already created app using ionic framework which is running in windows 8 as well as android.

But for this purpose I have created separate projects for both the platforms.Now I want to merge both the projects so that I will have a single project for both the platforms.

I read somewhere that we can use `merges` folder for that purpose.But I am not able to understand how to use that `merges` folder.

Please help here 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your platform specific files within merges folder in respective platform folder. like for android put files in merges/android. Cordova will copy these files into www folder at time of build command. If some files are already present in www folder, these will be merged with files within mergers folder. if same file is present in both places file within www will be replaced by file in merges folder.

for example suppose -
www folder of windows8 project containes two files windows.js and comman.js.
www folder of android project containes android.js and comman.js

if comman.js is same for both project. then you should keep comman.js file in www folder, put window.js file in merges/windows folder and android.js file in merges/android folder.

second scenario can be comman.js containes diffrent code for different platform then keep respective comman file in respective folder within merges folder.

I hope It will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Rupesh. For those who need more information about it can go through these link [forum thread](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/merges-folder-for-different-platform/6987) and [cordova git](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli#merges)